# Client error response [status code] 403 [reason phrase] Forbidden

Tags: api, linkedin-api

When I call linked in api method "v1/companies/{id}?format=json", I get error like "Client error response [status code] 403 [reason phrase] Forbidden". Application is authorized as group admin and it has permission: rw_company_admin. What I doing wrong?

Comment: { "errorCode": 0, "message": "Member {id} does not have permission to get company {id}", "requestId": "O4VGG27R0G", "status": 403, "timestamp": 1441261901219 } response from curl

Answer (score 0):

Earlier this year, LinkedIn's API changed in several ways (detailed here: https://developer.linkedin.com/blog/posts/2015/todays-changes)

One of those changes is that you need to be an official LinkedIn company administrator to make companies API calls now, so what's likely happening to you is that the company {id} value you are submitting is one that the authenticated member is not an admin of, and as a result, the call is forbidden.

You can make the following API request to test if the current user is an admin for a given company so that you know the subsequent request will work:

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v1/companies/{id}/relation-to-viewer/is-company-share-enabled?format=json
```

Additionally, you can get a list of all the companies that a member is the admin of with this call:

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v1/companies?format=json&is-company-admin=true
```

Complete documentation is available here:  https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/company-pages